# Conditional Multiple Infinite Scroll Instances

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I have a product-category page with infinite scroll loading next category. This is working fine but there are some categories that have several pages, so those categories should load next pages before loading next categories. Code loads next categories ok, but will not load next pages when a multipaged category comes. Code loads next pages if you are in a multipaged category, but then it will stop working.

This is the code I made so far: I made a conditional if next page exist, run infinite scroll for pages and restart function when last, if not, run infinite scroll for categories, and restart function when finished.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function foo() {

if ($('.page-numbers').length){

var $container = $('#main').infiniteScroll({
    path: ".page-numbers a.next",
    hideNav: ".woocommerce-pagination",
    append:  "#main ul.products",
    status: '.page-load-status',
    prefill: true,
    debug: true,
});

$container.on( 'history.infiniteScroll', function() {
  ga( 'set', 'page', location.pathname );
  ga( 'send', 'pageview' );
});


$container.on( 'last.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path ) {   
    foo.call(this)
});

    } else {

var nextURL;

function updateNextURL( doc ) {
  nextURL = $( doc ).find('.tax-pages a.next').attr('href');
}
// get initial nextURL
updateNextURL( document );

var $container2 = $('#main').infiniteScroll({
  // use function to set custom URLs
    path: function() {
    return nextURL;
    },
    hideNav: ".tax-pages",
    append:  ".products-wrap",
    status: '.page-load-status',
    debug: true,
    prefill: true,
});

// update nextURL on page load
$container2.on( 'load.infiniteScroll', function( event, response ) {
  updateNextURL( response );
});

$container2.on( 'history.infiniteScroll', function() {
  ga( 'set', 'page', location.pathname );
  ga( 'send', 'pageview' );
    foo.call(this)

});

}
    }());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs it, I solved it with a single infinitescroll instance and included the conditional on the next category link.

JS

```
 var nextURL;

function updateNextURL( doc ) {
  nextURL = $( doc ).find('.tax-pages a.next').attr('href');
}
// get initial nextURL
updateNextURL( document );

var $container2 = $('#main').infiniteScroll({
  // use function to set custom URLs
    path: function() {
    return nextURL;
    },
    hideNav: ".tax-pages",
    append:  ".products-wrap",
    status: '.page-load-status',
    debug: true,
    prefill: true,
});

// update nextURL on page load
$container2.on( 'load.infiniteScroll', function( event, response ) {
  updateNextURL( response );
});

$container2.on( 'history.infiniteScroll', function() {
  ga( 'set', 'page', location.pathname );
  ga( 'send', 'pageview' );
});
```

PHP: I added this code to [this function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222498/is-it-possible-to-get-a-previous-next-taxonomy-term-archive-url).

```
if ( $next_term ) 
    
$next_link = get_next_posts_link();

if ($next_link){

        $link[] = '<div class="tax-pages"> <a class="next" href="' . get_next_posts_page_link() . '">Next</a></div>';
        
        } else {
            
            
        $link[] = '<div class="tax-pages"> <a class="next" href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $next_term ) ) . '">' . $next_term->name . '</a></div>';
        
        }
```